# jQuery how to tell if child of "this" has a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap collapsible div:

```
<h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" class="collapse-button" collapse>
      simple collapsible
    </h3>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates dolor vel tenetur quod voluptate debitis nemo et mollitia dicta voluptas.
    </div>
```

They don't provide you of any built-in way to set a class on the collapsing element (here an H3) based on the status of the collapsed element.  Their code just sets a class of "in" on the collapsed element when it's showing.

What I need to do is create a generalized way to set a class on the H3 so I can display the right icon next to it.

I figured I could use jQuery to detect if the child div has the class "in" or not.

So far, this has eluded me.

If I select the child div by name, it works:

```
$(function() {
 $('.collapse-button').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var isOpen = $('#demo').hasClass('in'); 
   alert(isOpen);
 });
});
```

But I want to use this handler for **any** H3 and child div combo, so I need  to simple get the div thats the child of the object. So I tried things like

```
  $(this).find('div').hasClass('in');
```

To no avail.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Please note, in your current markup the `<div>` is ***not*** a child of the `<h3>` element. It is a ***sibling***. That's important and why you're selector is not working.

Comment: He could use `h3 + div.in` as a selector?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix You, could but I don't think it would be the desired effect. I think the OP wants to check the class of the collapsible div when the `<h3>` is clicked, not just target every `<div>` following an `<h3>`. That's my understanding at least. It may not be right though...

Comment: @War10ck that really all depends on the `this`. But it's still unclear where does the `this` come from.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Could be wrong, but from the wording it sounds like `$('#demo')` worked so the OP replaced that line with `var isOpen = $(this).find('div').hasClass('in');`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div is a sibling of the h3. The safest way, in case other siblings are added, or you switch them around is to add a parent for that h3 and div combo to traverse up to

```
<div class="togglewrapper"> 

   <h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" class="collapse-button" collapse>
      simple collapsible
    </h3>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates dolor vel tenetur quod voluptate debitis nemo et mollitia dicta voluptas.
    </div>

</div>
```

I'm assuming `$(this)` is `.collapse-button`. On click traverse up to the parent wrapper then count how many instances of `div.in`

```
$('.collapse-button').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   isOpen = $(this).closest('.togglewrapper').find('div.in').length; 
   alert(isOpen); // will be 0 or a positive integer, good enough to mean false/true
 });
```

Comment: Good idea.  I had just caught my error, and started using `var isOpen = $(this).siblings('div').hasClass('in');`

Answer (score 1):

The `<div>` is **not** a child of the `<h3>` element. It is a **sibling**. This is very important in terms of the selector you use.

Try this:

```
if($(this).next('.in').length) {
    ...
}
```

The full code would be something like the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('.collapse-button').on('click', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var isOpen = ($(this).next('.in').length) ? true : false; 
       alert(isOpen);
       // Set your class here...
       // var $next = $(this).next();
       // if($next.hasClass('in')) {
       //     $next.addClass('your-custom-class');
       // } else {
       //     $next.removeClass('your-custom-class');
       // }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

I've edited the code above to show how you could add/remove the custom class you want to create based on whether the `<div>` is opened or closed.